# How do I use a macro to name a sheet with yesterday's date?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

Here's what I have now that doesn't work,

```
spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setName(Today()-1);
```

I was wondering if I could just use 'Today() - 1' in cell A1 for example and pull the data from that.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To name a sheet with yesterday's date, Use a macro like this -

```
function myFunction() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var date = new Date()
  var ydate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(date.getTime()-(24*3600*1000)), "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy")
  spreadsheet.setName(ydate);
}
```

This is working perfecly.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, I was able to drop this into a function and get the desired result.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
var today=new Date();
var yesterday=new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate()-1);
```